# App called TV appeared then changed to videos

Tags: iphone

I saw the apple livestream saying the TV app would be pushed out to all iOS devices via an update. However, the app just appeared for me today without any update at all. It then was removed and the Videos app (which I'd removed) was added onto my phone.

Why did this happen? I have removed videos again - can I prevent it reinstalling?

Comment: Did you try to play videos you had previously purchased from Apple/iTunes or do a restore from backup recently?

Comment: @fsb nope, just unlocked my phone and the app was there.

Comment: The only time I've seen/heard/read about that app coming back is when someone tried to play a video or movie or trailer they got on iTunes.  If the app isn't installed then it will automatically install itself in order to play that video.  I was hoping that is what happened in your case, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when I changed to the US iTunes Store from the UK one. 'TV' is only available in the US. Logging out of iTunes & App Stores in Settings and logging in again has restored 'Videos' on my iPad

Comment: Yeah, this happened again when I did that, and switching back restored it to Videos, which I removed.